# varying the domain of an xarray dataset

Tags: python, dataset, python-xarray

I have something similar to the following dataset

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

lon_val = np.arange(0., 40., 1)
lat_val = np.arange(20., 60., 1)
vlevel_val = np.arange(0, 10, 1)

lon_da = xr.DataArray(lon_val, dims='lon', coords={'lon': lon_val}, attrs={'units': 'degrees_east'})
lat_da = xr.DataArray(lat_val, dims='lat', coords={'lat': lat_val}, attrs={'units': 'degrees_north'})
vertical_da = xr.DataArray(vlevel_val, dims='vertical', coords={'vertical': vlevel_val}, attrs={'units': 'km'})

data_values = np.random.rand(len(lon_val), len(lat_val), len(vlevel_val)) * 0.9

ds = xr.Dataset(
    {
        "data":(("lon", "lat", "vlevel"), data_values),
    },
    coords={
        "lon": lon_da.data,
        "lat": lat_da.data,
        "vlevel": vertical_da.data}
    )

print(ds)
```

I want to vary the domain horizontally (e.g. take 25%, 10%,... of the whole domain).

Then put the data_values of each subdomain into a function to calculate something and then take the mean over the results of each subdomain (e.g. for 25% over the 4 subdomains).

The goal is to better understand the spatial dependency of the data. more specifically if smaller domains result in bigger errors.

I was thinking about using the groupby_bins method but didn't know how to effectively subdivide the domain with it.